# Powershell: Filtering properties by an array of invalid characters

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to filter properties from active directory contacts to find invalid characters and then replace them. My problem is defining an array of invalid characters to use as a filter.
I imagine i'm tackling this incorrectly but if anyone could advise where i'm going wrong and a best method to tackle this one it would be appreciated.

```
$invalidchars = '[^\p{L}\p{Nd}\S\(\)\-\_\!\#\$\%\&\''\*\+\/\=\?\^\`\{\}\\\~\ ]'
$query = Get-ADObject -Searchbase 'OU=etc,DC=etc' -Server 'etc' -Properties * -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "contact"' 
$query | Where-Object {$_.propertyname -Like "$invalidchars"}
```

Once I can filter the properties i need that are incorrect the plan is to replace the bad characters in a variable and then set the new sanitized properties back in place.

Comment: You'll want to use `-match` instead of `-like`

Comment: Thanks Mathias,

-match should be used for regular expressions
" \ _ " has troubles being recognized within powershell (but was unecessary anyway